# Correct approach for calculating excited states of circular quantum dot under effective mass approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

From Asnani, Mahajan et al, Pramana Journal Of Physics 73 #3 (2009) p574-580 "Effective mass theory of a two-dimensional quantum dot in the presence of magnetic field", which can be seen here: http://www.ias.ac.in/pramana/v73/p573/fulltext.pdf

The paper gives an equation (10) derived from the case of a finite circular well with ratio of effective masses $\beta=m_i/m_o$, ($m_i$ inside the well, and $m_o$ outside):

$$\frac{J_1(k_i R)}{J_0(k_i R)} = \beta \frac{2 k_o R + 1}{2 k_i R}$$

Where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and $k_i = \sqrt{2 m_i E/ \hbar^2}$.

The equation, if solved (though computationally), will give many energy values. At the same time, while solving the Schrodinger equations for particle inside as well as outside the box, if I take angular momentum index $\ell$ not equal to zero it will give "higher" energy values.

So my query is:

> What are the energy eigenvalues (or the excited states), the one which we calculate by solving equation (10) or the ones that we can calculate if we take different values of $\ell$?
>
> Also, The equation (10) can be solved for many values of E (energy) , what are those values physically ? Why only the value near 2.40483 (the root of Bessel function of first kind of order zero) is chosen as the ground state energy value (see asymptotic analysis - section 3 of the paper)  ?

Comment: It might be in your interests to include Equation (10) (and likely some of the prior equations that set up the desired equation), rather than force people to open up a PDF and read.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: I've added the equation, explanation, paper details and fixed the title so that people can see what it's about.

Comment: Thanks ! I am new to Physics SE. Not very familiar with MathJax

Comment: Somebody help me please ! The question has been modified and I am seeking answer to this question. Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The paper addresses the case of a circular, finite quantum well with different electron effective masses inside and outside the well.

The equation you point to is the result of a derivation from the time-independent Schrodinger equation, effective mass approximation and BenDaniel-Duke boundary conditions. It is also, however, dependent on the statement after equation 3:

> The ground state wave function will be independent of $\phi$ and angular moment[um] index $l$.

This is the basis for separating $g(r)$ from the rest, leading up to the derivation of Eq 10, and indicates that its solution is only relevant to the ground state. Any questions about higher states are not answered with that equation.

You are perhaps confused by the labelling; in the equation, $k_i$, which often means the $i$th wavevector; in this instance it actually means the value of $k$ inside the dot. So solving the equation will not yield a set of wavefunctions but a single ground state.

Comment: The equation (10) can be solved for many values of E (energy) , what are those values physically ? Why only the value near \alpha_0 (the root of bessel function of first kind of order zero) is chosen ?